# Why is this Javascript code returning the last number only?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript array which I wanted to slice and put in a new array, but the new array prints out only the last value.

I tried using for loop

```
let array = [5, 6, 9, 7, 10, 17, 20, 35, 105, 140];
let slicedArray;
const removeNumbers = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 5 === 0 && array[i] % 7 === 0) {
      slicedArray = [...array.splice(i, 1)];
    }
  }
  return slicedArray;
}

console.log(removeNumbers());
```

I expected 35,105, and 140 as an output, but the actual output is just 140.

Comment: Because you are always resetting `slicedArray`'s value `slicedArray=[...]`, not appending (pushing) to it

Comment: Why do you want 7 to be included in your desired output? It's not a multiple of 5

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter` instead, to create a new array based on elements of a different array that pass a test:

```js
let array = [5, 6, 9, 7, 10, 17, 20, 35, 105, 140];
const newArr = array.filter(num => num % 5 === 0 && num % 7 === 0);
console.log(newArr);
```

If you have to mutate the existing array as well, then push the spliced element to the new array while splicing (don't reassign the `slicedArray`, just push to it):

```js
const array = [5, 6, 9, 7, 10, 17, 20, 35, 105, 140];
const removeNumbers = () => {
  const slicedArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 5 === 0 && array[i] % 7 === 0) {
      slicedArray.push(...array.splice(i, 1));
      // Need to subtract 1 from i here, so that this removed index gets iterated over again next time
      i--;
    }
  }
  return slicedArray;
}


console.log(removeNumbers());
```

7 is not included because it's not a multiple of 5.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful! Yes, I said 7 by mistake.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (click the checkbox) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You should only be getting 35, 105 and 140 according to your if statement. Since you want your numbers to bi divisible by 5 and 7.

The problem was you did not append your numbers in the array and mutated the array when using splice method. Because of mutation number 105 wasn't included.

```
let array = [5, 6, 9, 7, 10, 17, 20, 35, 105, 140];
let slicedArray = [];
const removeNumbers = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 5 === 0 && array[i] % 7 === 0) {

      slicedArray = [...slicedArray, ...[...array].splice(i, 1)];

    }

  }

  return slicedArray;
}


console.log(removeNumbers());
```

Comment: My bad, I meant 35,105, and 140. 105 satisfies the condition too.

Comment: @mimiethio check my code again, the problem was that you mutated you array

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing the elements in the array like this:

```
let array = [5,6,9,7,10,17,20,35,105,140];
let slicedArray;    
const removeNumbersTest = () => {
 for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(array[i] % 5 === 0 && array[i] % 7 === 0){
     slicedArray.push(...array.splice(i,1));
     }
   }
   return slicedArray;
}
```

The code above should do what you wanted it to do, just check the logic before pushing the elements in the array.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this before, it doesn't work. It nests the new array into another array. Thanks though! I found the solution now.

Comment: @Ruan Montelo your code is wrong you are mutating the object it should be like this
 ```slicedArray.push(...[...array].splice(i, 1));```
Also you did not assign the value of array to you slicedArray variable which will cause an error when trying to push

Answer (score 0):

You simply can push the target items on the slicedArray:

```
let array =[5,6,9,7,10,17,20,35,105,140];
const slicedArray=[];  //Array is mutable with const keyword
const removeNumbers= () =>{
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] % 5 === 0 && array[i] % 7 === 0){

          slicedArray.push(array[i]);

         }

    }

    return slicedArray;
}


console.log(removeNumbers());
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code and some minor issues:

1. `array.slice()` returns removed items and you have to collect them sequentially.
   Solution: Push the items returned from `array.slice()` to the collecting array using `array.push()`.
2. `array.slice()` modifies the array in place. Say the current index `i` is set to `7`, that item `35` gets removed by the slicing operation from `array`. But now the next number `105` is shifted one position downwards. The for-loop continues with index `8` which now contains number `140`.
   Solution: Modify the for-loop index when an item is removed.
3. The naming `slicedArray` is misleading. Better name would be `removedNumbers`.
4. The variable `removedNumbers` should be a local to the function `removeNumber()`.
5. Using a global variable `array` is not perfect. Maybe you would like to change your code to `removeNumbers()` takes a parameter. I omitted this fix from my example.

A fixed solution could look like:

(Please note the `i--` which fixes the index to test in the next for-loop iteration the same position again.)

```
let array = [5,6,9,7,10,17,20,35,105,140];

const removeNumbers = () => {
  let removedNumbers = [];

  for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] % 5 === 0 && array[i] % 7 === 0) {

      removedNumbers.push(...array.splice(i--,1));

    }
  }
  return removedNumbers;
}

console.log("Removed numbers:", removeNumbers());
console.log("Remaining numbers:", array);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you expect 7, 35,105, and 140 then append to the list and change your `if` to

```
if (array[i] % 7 === 0 && array[i] % 5 === 0)
```